# Official Transcripts From Indian University

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, united-states, transcript-of-records, india

Most of the US graduate programs I'm applying to require official transcripts sent in a sealed envelope from the issuing university itself and not by the candidate. I visited my registrar office and they are willing to provide sealed envelopes containing official transcripts to me but they do not post these envelopes on their own. Will the US universities accept the envelope sent by the candidate instead by the university address?

I have written to the concerned office/graduate officer in the universities, but I think due to Thanksgiving, I have not yet received a response. Also they get thousands of emails so I’m not sure how soon I will get a response from them.

And timing is crucial because my university is in different state altogether which is a day’s journey from my place by train. And Indian universities don’t do well with telephonic or email support, so things have to be tackled in person. Apart from the cost issues.

Comment: How would the US University work out the sender identity? Go ahead please.

Comment: In India, The sender's information is mentioned on the envelope so the receiver knows from where the post has arrived. Hence the dilemma of sending sealed envelope on your own or through one's Alma Mater.

Answer (score 5):

I'm in the US, graduated from US university. I've personally send sealed transcripts. If they don't do this normally, ask the university to use an official stamp and place it across the seal of the envelope. That provides proof that the transcript hasn't been tampered with.

This [link to a PDF](https://web.uri.edu/admission/files/ExamplesofProperlySealedEnvelopesforTranscripts.pdf) from University of Rhode Island shows several examples of properly sealed transcripts.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it yourself. I have faced the same issue with UPTU where they just provided me with sealed transcript and I had to post them by Fedex